# assignment in pthreads application

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I have a linux multithread application in C++.
In this application in `class App` offer variable `Status`:

```
class App {
...
typedef enum { asStop=0, asStart, asRestart, asWork, asClose } TAppStatus;
TAppStatus Status; 
...
}
```

All threads are often check `Status` by calling `GetStatus()` function.

```
inline TAppStatus App::GetStatus(){ return Status };
```

Other functions of the application can assign a different values to a `Status` variable by calling `SetStatus()` function and do not use Mutexes.

```
void App::SetStatus( TAppStatus aStatus ){ Status=aStatus };
```

Edit: All threads use `Status` in `switch` operator:

```
switch ( App::GetStatus() ){ case asStop: ... case asStart: ... };
```

1. Is the assignment in this case, an atomic operation?
2. Is this correct code?

Thanks.

Comment: I strongly doubt that enums are threadsafe... I doubt that the assignment is a atomic operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no portable way to implement synchronized variables in C99 or C++03 and pthread library does not provide one either. You can:

- Use C++0x `<atomic>` header (or C1x `<stdatomic.h>`). Gcc does support it for C++ if given `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x` option since version 4.4.
- Use the Linux-specific `<linux/atomic.h>` (this is implementation used by kernel, but it should be usable from userland as well).
- Use GCC-specific [`__sync_*` builtin functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).
- Use some other library that provides atomic operations like [glib](http://www.gtk.org).
- Use locks, but that's orders of magnitude slower compared to the fast operation itself.

Note: As Martinho pointed out, while they are called "atomic", for store and load it's not the atomic property (operation cannot be interrupted and load always sees or does not see the whole store, which is usually true of 32-bit stores and loads) but the ordering property (if you store a and than b, nobody may get new value of b and than old value of a) that is hard to get but necessary in this case.

Comment: Sorry, what "the Linux-specific"? Didn't you forget a word there?

Comment: @Martinho: Oops, sorry, forgot quotes so the header name in `<>` got dropped.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely upon the enum representation chosen. For x86, I believe, then all assignment operations of the operating system's word size (so 32bit for x86 and 64bit for x64) and alignment of that size as well are atomic, so a simple read and write is atomic.

Even assuming that it is the correct size *and* alignment, this *doesn't* mean that these functions are thread-safe, depends on what the status is used for.

Edit: In addition, the compiler's optimizer may well wreak havoc if there are no uses of atomic operations or other volatile accesses.

Edit to your edit: No, that's not thread safe at all. If you converted it manually into a jump table then you might be thread-safe, I'll need to think about it for a little while.

Comment: Without `volatile` keyword, it's never atomic.

Comment: "Operations on volatile variables are not atomic, nor do they  establish a proper happens-before relationship for threading." volatile only means "Hey, you there, the compiler, don't optimize access to this thing, ok?"

Comment: @Martinho: On *some* platforms declaring things volatile is enough to make store and load atomic and the "don't optimize access" implies "don't reorder across sequencing point" which on *some platforms* is enough to define ordering (the instructions are ordered correctly, but caches may break it).

Comment: @Jan: Ok, it works sometimes. But "Without volatile keyword, it's never atomic." is wrong. Atomic only means it happens on a single step. It can certainly be atomic without volatile. They're related, but orthogonal things.

Comment: @DeadMG: It will never be thread-safe unless you make the operation use appropriate barrier instruction or lock prefix (as appropriate for given platform) and you need inline assembly for that. Most CPUs don't ensure coherency between L1 caches of multiple CPUs/cores without those.

Comment: @Martinho: You are right. "Atomic" is not the problem; the ordering is.

Answer (score 0):

On certain architecture this assignment might be atomic (by accident), but even if it is, this code is wrong. Compiler and hardware may perform various optimizations, with might break this "atomicity". Look at: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4714369049736584770#

Use locks or atomic http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/atomic/atomic.html variable to fix it.